# Venous PO2 and anemic hypoxia

Tags: practice-of-medicine, hematology, hypoxia, anemia

Why does venous PO<sub>2</sub> decrease in [anemic hypoxia](https://www.britannica.com/science/anemic-hypoxia)? Shouldn't it be constant as PO<sub>2</sub> is a measure of the dissolved oxygen?

Comment: The linked reference to the condition states why. "The amount of functional hemoglobin is too small, and hence the capacity of the blood to carry oxygen is too low". Can you please explain what you don't quite understand? Then we hopefully can explain it to you